# Roman to Integer - Python

Tags: python

I've currently go the following code to solve the below question:

https://leetcode.com/problems/roman-to-integer/

```
def romanToInt(s: str) -> int:
    dict = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10,'L': 50,'C': 100, 'C': 100,'D': 500,'M': 1000}
    s = list(s)
    x = 0
    y = 1
    max_count = len(s) - 1
    value = 0

    print(s)
#Iterate through the numbers one by one with two pointers x and y. 
#If x is bigger than y move both 1 point forward.
#If x is less than y move both 2 points forward.
    while y <= max_count:
        if dict[s[x]] > dict[s[y]]:
            value =  value + dict[s[x]]
            x += 1
            y += 1
        elif dict[s[x]] < dict[s[y]]:
            value =  value + (dict[s[y]] - dict[s[x]])
            x += 2
            y += 2
        else:
            value = value + dict[s[x]] + dict[s[y]]
            x += 1
            y += 1
    return value

print(romanToInt(s = 'III'))
```

So currently the issue I am facing is calculating an extra value during the iteration process. I know the issue is with the pointer x movement and calculation, I just cant seem to figure it out.

Any assistance will help.

Comment: Please read [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and show what happens when you run the code, and how that is different from what is supposed to happen. Trace through the logic of the code and figure out where the behaviour diverges from what you expect.

Comment: I believe that your `else:
            value = value + dict[s[x]] + dict[s[y]]` should be `else:
            value = value + dict[s[x]] ` otherwise you double count your `y` on your next iteration. To debug, consider `s='III'`

Comment: This question should come with a [mcve], accompanied by the expected and actual output it produces. Also, developing things like this is much easier when using test-driven development. Also, as already suggested, stepping through the code with a debugger helps.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment. For your `else` do not add in the value of `s[y]` as `s[y]` will be your NEXT `s[x]` and you will double count it.

Furthermore you will need to check when you've reached the end of the string to ensure that you capture the last value when appropriate.

Consider:

```
def romanToInt(s: str) -> int:
    dict = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10,'L': 50,'C': 100, 'C': 100,'D': 500,'M': 1000}
    s = list(s)
    x = 0
    y = 1
    max_count = len(s) - 1
    value = 0

    
#Iterate through the numbers one by one with two pointers x and y. 
#If x is bigger than y move both 1 point forward.
#If x is less than y move both 2 points forward.
    while x <= max_count:
        if y == len(s): 
            value = value + dict[s[x]]
            break
        elif dict[s[x]] > dict[s[y]]:
            value =  value + dict[s[x]]
            x += 1
            y += 1
        elif dict[s[x]] < dict[s[y]]:
            value =  value + (dict[s[y]] - dict[s[x]])
            x += 2
            y += 2
        else:
            value = value + dict[s[x]] 
            x += 1
            y += 1
    return value


print(romanToInt(s = 'III'))
print(romanToInt(s = 'IV'))
print(romanToInt(s = 'VI'))
print(romanToInt(s = 'V'))
```

---

```
3
4
6
5
```

Comment: thank you for this. I realize my mistakes now.

Comment: You were VERY close.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def romanToInt(s: str) -> int:
    dict = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10,'L': 50,'C': 100,'D': 500,'M': 1000}

    total_value = 0
    last_value = None

    for letter in s[::-1]:
        current_value = dict[letter]
        if last_value is None or last_value <= current_value:
            total_value += current_value
        else:
            total_value -= current_value

        last_value = current_value
        
    return total_value
```

Its better to just use for loop and add or substract the current value to total... for example IX = 40. When youre at I you see that X is bigger, so
you can substract 10, then add 50 when you get to X. -10+50 -> 40

In your case you could change it to this:

```
def romanToInt(s: str) -> int:
    dict = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10,'L': 50,'C': 100, 'C': 100,'D': 500,'M': 1000}
    s = list(s)
    x = 0
    y = 1
    max_count = len(s) - 1
    value = 0


    while y <= max_count:
        if dict[s[x]] > dict[s[y]]:
            value += dict[s[x]]
            x += 1
            y += 1
        elif dict[s[x]] < dict[s[y]]:
            value -= dict[s[x]]
            x += 1
            y += 1
        else:
            value += dict[s[x]] 
            x += 1
            y += 1

    value += dict[s[x]] 

    return value
```

so you only need x+=1 only once and you could simplify it to

```
def romanToInt(s: str) -> int:
    dict = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10,'L': 50,'C': 100, 'C': 100,'D': 500,'M': 1000}
    s = list(s)
    x = 0
    y = 1
    max_count = len(s) - 1
    value = 0

    while y <= max_count:
        if dict[s[x]] < dict[s[y]]:
            value -= dict[s[x]]
        else:
            value += dict[s[x]] 
        x += 1
        y += 1

    value += dict[s[x]] 

    return value
```

keep in mind that this wont include the last character (index limit) so you have to add that separately